# Drag and Drop component Frame to another Frame

Tags: c#

I need to drag and drop a component from a frame1 to a frame2 in C#. But when this its dropped I need to know what is the position of the component in the new frame. thanks ...

Comment: what do you mean by frame here ?

Comment: There are no frames like that in C#, perhaps in HTML/ASP.NET, WPF or WinForms? (what a frame might be in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the following to learn about dragging and dropping:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dandtutorial.aspx

The `X` & `Y` properties values of the [DragEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drageventargs.aspx) of the `OnDragDrop` event handler could be usefull in finding the position of your component.